# AJAX, Obtain answer from server and after stop php's function work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Using jquery AJAX I send data on server, after I print data on server so:

php code:

```
function someFunc () 
    echo json_encode("some");
}
```

and Obtain in js this data so:

```
$.ajax({
   // here code for send
   success: function (htm) {
            htm = JSON.parse(htm);
            alert(htm);
        }
    });
```

this works, but when I need obtain asnwer from server and after stop php functions work, in js I dont obtain data, that is, this not works

```
function someFunc () 
    echo json_encode("some");
    return false;
}
```

without `return false;` works. Tell please Why?

Comment: what output do you get with the "return false;". because i'm pretty sure that should be working.

Comment: js consol tells that `htm` is undefined

Comment: maybe just call the php file and look at the output? might be some error in your code and the result is not valid json

Comment: Without `return false` I obtain in js "some", that is php code works

Comment: well, it should work with "return false;" but i cant tell with just the snippet you posted, you probably have some other error. exit; should work too

Comment: if write `exit` instead `return`, all works, very strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just exit() instead of returning false.

Comment: What is differnce in this case?

Comment: exit will finish the execution of the script, return will jump out of the function, script still running (as long as there is code to process)

Comment: Exit will stop from running anymore PHP so you only get the data you need.

Comment: Yes, I know differnce between exit and return, but why works exit() "his really works" and dont works return ?

Comment: You're not returning anything.  You're echoing out the JSON data.  Once it's echoed, you just need to stop executing PHP with exit.  No need to return anything.